# Can not config Header security middleware CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, iframe, cakephp-3.x, x-frame-options

I have a site built with CakePHP, default it doesn't allow subdomain embed on iframe.

1. I configured Frame Option on `nginx/conf.d` and now my homepage can be embedded in an iframe of a subdomain.
2. However, another post cannot be embedded on a subdomain's iframe. (exp: http://example.net/postabc will not display). I tried to change options on Header security middleware(please read below).
3. Is there anywhere I need to change the configuration to so all my posts can be displayed?

```
<?php
namespace Cake\Http\Middleware;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class SecurityHeadersMiddleware
{
    protected $headers = [];

    public function noSniff()
    {
        $this->headers['x-content-type-options'] = 'nosniff';

        return $this;
    }
    public function noOpen()
    {
        $this->headers['x-download-options'] = 'noopen';

        return $this;
    }

    public function setReferrerPolicy($policy = 'same-origin')
    {
        $available = [
            'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin',
            'origin-when-cross-origin',
            'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
            'unsafe-url'
        ];

        $this->checkValues($policy, $available);
        $this->headers['referrer-policy'] = $policy;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setXFrameOptions($option = 'allow-from', $url = 'http://subdomain.example.net')
    {
        $this->checkValues($option, ['deny', 'sameorigin', 'allow-from']);

        if ($option === 'allow-from') {
            if (empty($url)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('The 2nd arg $url can not be empty when `allow-from` is used');
            }
            $option .= ' ' . $url;
        }

        $this->headers['x-frame-options'] = $option;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setXssProtection($mode = 'block')
    {
        $mode = (string)$mode;

        if ($mode === 'block') {
            $mode = '1; mode=block';
        }

        $this->checkValues($mode, ['1', '0', '1; mode=block']);
        $this->headers['x-xss-protection'] = $mode;

        return $this;
    }


    public function setCrossDomainPolicy($policy = 'all')
    {
        $this->checkValues($policy, ['all', 'none', 'master-only', 'by-content-type', 'by-ftp-filename']);
        $this->headers['x-permitted-cross-domain-policies'] = $policy;

        return $this;
    }


    protected function checkValues($value, array $allowed)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, $allowed)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Invalid arg `%s`, use one of these: %s',
                $value,
                implode(', ', $allowed)
            ));
        }
    }


    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        foreach ($this->headers as $header => $value) {
            $response = $response->withHeader($header, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is the CakePHP core middleware, you are not supposed to modify it, and if you were, you should mention what exactly it is that you actually modified. Please read **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html** on how and where to use middleware, and then show _your_ code that utilizes the middleware.

Comment: @ndm can i disable this middleware?

Comment: Any middleware can be disabled / not used...

Comment: @ndm please give tutorial do it, i searched but still can not solved this ! thanks !